# How to send the text in django-select2 field instead of the id at form submission?

Tags: django, django-select2

This is a two-part question

**Problem description**
I have a form with a field that uses ModelSelect2TagWidget (that accepts free-text as an input). when the user enters a number as free-text, it is converted to the object whose id is the number entered as a free-text. For example, if the user enters "11" as free-text
[image]
and the form is submitted, the entry is automatically converted to the value whose id is 11 in the database
[image]

On the other hand, if the user chooses one of the available choices (not a free-text), the id of the selected choice in the select2 field is sent in the request as in the screenshot.
[image]

The problem is when the form is submitted, ***I have no way to distinguish whether the submitted value is an id or a free-text number entered by the user.***

To solve this problem, I am thinking about sending the text of the input field instead of the id as follows
[image]

1. How can I send the text of the selected choice instead of the id in the request?
2. As this is a ModelSelect2TagWidget field, it accepts free-text. Is there a better way to distinguish between the id of a selected choice or if the user enters a number as a free-text?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm running with the same issue, have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following solution. Further links [AutoResponseView](https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django_select2.html#django_select2.views.AutoResponseView)

Subclassed `AutoResponseView` from django-select2. In `response_obj` set the "`id`" value to the field of the model you want to use. In my case was `obj.name` (instead of `obj.pk` in AutoResponseView itself)

in a new file `select2_classes.py` inside my app

```
class MyResponseView(AutoResponseView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       self.widget = self.get_widget_or_404()
       self.term = kwargs.get("term", request.GET.get("term", ""))
       self.object_list = self.get_queryset()

       context = self.get_context_data()

       response_obj = {
         "results": [
            {"text": self.widget.label_from_instance(obj), "id": obj.name}
            for obj in context["object_list"]
        ],
        "more": context["page_obj"].has_next(),
       }
       response = JsonResponse(response_obj)
       return response
```

In urls.py inside app folder

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    path('my_search/', MyResponseView.as_view(), name='my-search'),
]
```

In forms.py, added a widget to the corresponding field

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class MyWidget(ModelSelect2MultipleTagWidget):
    attributes = {'data-minimum-input-length': 0}

    def get_queryset(self):
        return MyModel.objects.all() # or filtered queryset 


class ListSearchForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(
          label=...,
          help_text=...,
          widget=MyWidget(data_url=reverse_lazy("app:my-search")))
```